# Birt report Rest api Data source

Tags: json, api, rest, birt

We are using Birt report viewer to create reporting pages. 
We use jdbc data source to connect with a Oracle database. 
But is it possible to use a rest api (json format) as data source for the reports?
Does someone has experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

BIRT has no build in JSON data source. However there are some community JSON data source plugins, but all of them I have seen are very low level and not comfortable to use, so I do not recommand any of them here.

You could create a "scripted data source" where you connect to your URL and parse the result by yourself but this is also not very comfortable. [Someone tried it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49850768/1515052) so you have a starting point.

If you are in charge of the infrastructure providing the JSON output it would be easier to add an export to XML and use the BIRT build in XML data source.