# Birt scripted datasource Javascript code is not executing

Tags: javascript, datasource, birt

I'm trying to get json response from a RESTful API in Birt's scripted datasource option. So i'm referring this Actuate's tutorial 
[Actuate's tutorial for scripted datasource](http://otadocs.opentext.com/documentation/ihub3/help/adg/adg65/index.html#page/ADG/ProgramDataAccess.1.2.html) and this question that has been raised before 
[Stackoverflow question regarding Birt with RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725274/birt-with-restful-apis/49850768#49850768). So i'm using the datasource's and data set's corresponding `open()` and `fetch()` methods to define the js code. But the issue is the js code is simply not executed even when i'm trying to debug with simple `window.alert("test");`.

It gives this exceptions :

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DtEScriptExecutor handleJS
WARNING: Fail to execute script in function __bm_OPEN(). Source:
```

and

```
ReferenceError: "window" is not defined. (/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="4"]/method[@name="open"]#5)
org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: Fail to execute script in function __bm_OPEN(). Source:
```

Is there a dependency or jar I should add to `scriptlib` folder? Or is this some other issue? 
Thanks in advance.

edit:

It seems the alert function is not going to work since they use Rhino in server side scripting. So is there any way to debug the script?

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse BIRT's Javascript with Javascript inside a browser!

Even more confusing:
You can use Javascript at different stages in BIRT, and some of them work when viewing the output in a browser...

BIRT uses Javascript, but doesn't know alert() or the window object.
These are only defined if a script runs inside the browser.

Most of BIRTs scripting happens at generation time - not in the browser (compare this with node.js, for example).

If you want to output debug messages, do this by calling Java vom inside the script.